# Lego NXT Color Sensor: Print color as string? (Java)

Tags: java, colors, sensors, nxt

How can I print the string value of the scanned color on the NXT-Screen? My code currently looks like this:

```
 ColorSensor colorSensor = new ColorSensor(SensorPort.S4);
 ColorSensor.Color color = colorSensor.getColor();
 System.out.println("Color = " + colorSensor.getColorID() + " " + color.getColor());
```

It only prints out the number of the color twice, but I want it to print "red" or "blue" and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: Is the number the hex RGB value?  If so, you could write a method that looks at the separate R, G, and B components to see which are dominate.  For instance, `255,12,46` would be dominantly Red, `189,20,198` would be dominantly purple (red and blue are close to each other).

Comment: There are already methods for getting the R, G and B components. However, the NXT is able to calculate the resulting color by itself, so I don't think this is necessary.

It returns a number for the resulting color but I don´t know what color they stand for.

Comment: Google found this when I searched for "lego nxt color chart": http://www.hitechnic.com/contents/media/Color%20Number.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I found several color charts the NXT can use if it has the right color sensor. The one I have can (or should) only recognize 6 different colours, but with the code above it once printed 0 and after that 7. So that would make at least 8 colours. That´s why I wanted it to print the color as string, I´m getting confused with those numbers ^^

Comment: According to the Lego site (http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Color-Sensor-9694), the 9694 sensor does "black, white, and 6 colors in between".  This one also seems to have a chart of some of the colors: http://www.philohome.com/colcomp/cc.htm

Comment: Oh that makes sense... I overread that black and white are not counted as colors. Thank you! If somebody knows how to print out the color still feel free to comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't really print "Red" or "blue" out. Each color has a number. 
Here is the example of my other answer (click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641882/how-to-calibrate-the-lego-nxt-color-sensor-with-lejos-nxj/56894059#56894059)):

```java
public void isWhite() {
    ColorSensor cs = new ColorSensor(SensorPort.S3);
    cs.setFloodlight(false);
    if (cs.getColor().getColor() == Color.WHITE) {            
      System.out.println("It's white!");
    }     
    System.out.println("It's not white...");
    }
```

So you have to make your own method to print out which color it is. 
[Click here if you want to see the constants of the colors](http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/api/constant-values.html#lejos.nxt.SensorConstants.BLUE)